How do I get the clients connected to a Cassandra instance via springboot application?
I'm trying to fetch cassandra clientip address and the executed query via springboot application. How to push these metrics to prometheus?
Can someone please help me how to create custom metrics for cassandra and push to prometheus ?

There's a new feature called Virtual Tables that was added in Cassandra 4.0 (CASSANDRA-7622). These tables provide the ability to expose metrics and configuration via CQL.
The table system_views.clients stores information about connected clients (apps) which include:

the remote IP address of the client
logged in user (if authentication is enabled)
native CQL binary protocol version
driver name & version
whether SSL is used, etc

You can find out more details in my answer to question 327551 on DBA Stack Exchange.
Since these are accessible via CQL, you can simply retrieve the information you require via the Java driver. But if your intention is to simply push them to Prometheus, I think it's unnecessary to have to write a Spring Boot application for it.
I would suggest you have a look at the Metric Collector for Apache Cassandra (MCAC). It uses collectd to collect and aggregate metrics and exports them to a Prometheus instance. Additionally, it comes with pre-built Grafana dashboards so you can immediately visualise the data.
MCAC is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Thanks for the info. I have an existing springboot application which connects to cassandra. So, thought of instrumenting cassandra application metrices and push it to prometheus. Can you please suggest the ideal way to proceed further ?

I'm trying to fetch only application level cassandra metrics. Do not want to fetch cassandra infra level metrics as I already have them in place

Can we log cassandra query which is executed in the application ?
